# android type mismatch on string sqlite view

Tags: android, sqlite, list, type-mismatch

anyone know why this is giving me an error on weights?

error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String

```
 public void viewWeightHandler(View view) {
    List weights = this.dh.selectAll();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("Previous Weights:\n");
    for (String weight : weights) {
        sb.append(weight + "\n");
    }
    Log.d("WEIGHT", "weight size - " + weights.size());
    output.setText(sb.toString());
}
```

output is a textview to display results

weight is what the user has inputed

weights is the list that is produced.

as far as i know this above should loop and for each weight it should insert it into weights and display as such (if input is 1, 22,3)

> 1
>
> 22
>
> 3

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your for loop:

```
for (Object weight : weights) {
    sb.append(weight.toString() + "\n");
}
```

The problem is you got the weights out of the database as type `Object`. But you can't just treat `Object`s as `String`s without doing some sort of casting first.

Comment: @TuffyG refer to my answer: You iterate with variable of type `List`, however the elements in `weights` are not lists, thus the error.

Answer (score 2):

I think you make an error in iterating the weights (using the enhanced for loop):

```
  for (List weight : weights) {
      sb.append(weight + "\n");
  }
```

Declaring it that way, means that every element of weights should be list (thus the iterating variable is also list). However, I think this is not the case. I do not exactly know what kind of elements the list store, I would assume it is `String`:

```
    List<String> weights =      this.dh.selectAll();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("Previous Weights:\n");
    for (String weight : weights) {
        sb.append(weight + "\n");
    }
```

It is very bad practise to use raw type, without generic parameter, it is harder to understand, disables the content assist and may lead to errors like yours (thus I added the `<String>`.

However, the error I am correcting will not cause compilation error but `ClassCastException` at runtime.